# PHP MongoDB `fields` param not working

Tags: php, mongodb

According to the php docs http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.findone.php, the following query should return only the `emails` field of the document.  Yet it returns them all!  I have found that no matter what I put in the `fields` array, it returns all fields.

```
$row = $Entities->findOne( [ "emails.email" => $address ], array("emails" => 1) );
```

Any idea what is wrong?

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 using php 7.  Info from composer.json

```
"packages": [
    {
        "name": "mongodb/mongodb",
        "version": "1.0.4",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library.git",
            "reference": "302de20d8302183e1c70b335d81798cec5bcebd4"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mongodb/mongo-php-library/zipball/302de20d8302183e1c70b335d81798cec5bcebd4",
            "reference": "302de20d8302183e1c70b335d81798cec5bcebd4",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "ext-mongodb": "^1.1.0",
            "php": ">=5.4"
        },
        "type": "library",
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "MongoDB\\": "src/"
            },
            "files": [
                "src/functions.php"
            ]
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

try : 
`$row = $Entities->findOne( array("email" => $address), array("emails") );`

According to the documentation : if you use `array("emails" => 0)` in the second argument, it will return all the fields except `emails` so logically if you put `array("emails" => 1)` it will return all the fields including `emails`, so if you want to specify the fields you should use just `array("emails")`

Comment: Tried: `$row = $Entities->findOne( array( "emails.email" => $address ), array("firstName" => 0) );` and still it returns all of the fields!  In JS if you do `emails:1` it will only return `_id` and `emails`.  I read somewhere else that php is the same.   I have tried making it a 1 and 0, and still to no avail!  It won't kill my program but is a little annoying.